# Handle usage on Windows CE

Tags: c#, c++, resources, windows-ce, handle

I need to monitor handle usage on a Windows CE box.

Essentially I want to be able to see handle usage over time to tell if my applications / services are leaking handles (which I believe they are).

Any example code would be great.

Comment: I'm a little confused.  You want to knpw "what % of handles have been used" but there isn't some pool of handles from which it hands them out.  The max number a process can have, I think, is 32768 but if you're hitting that, you've got some other problems (and would likely be out of Virtual Memory long before then).  What problem, exactly, are you trying to solve?

Comment: Essentially our CE box dies, which we think is due to handles not being closed properly.  Our memory and disk usage is stable and we have already identified a number of places where handles are not being closed correctly which we can fix.  But we want to be 100% certain that we are not leaking any more handles.  I'd be very grateful of any advice.

Comment: Ah, yes I've seen similar behavior when doing drivers.  Unfortuantely there isn't a place you can track handle allocations, we simply used process of elimination to determine what driver was doing it, and then brute-forced our way through the code.

Answer (score 0):

While it is not exactly what you are looking for, I can recommend a little tool that we are using called CodeSnitch (http://www.entrek.com/codesnitch.html). It will instrument your code and keep track allocation and de-allocation of resources, including handles. I have used it to clean up several of our applications with great success. You can download a 2 week trial version to try it out.